# Project texture out of view to Selected Polygons/Surface in Blender. - Sketchfab in video doin it

Tags: texturing, camera, texture-painting

[Sketchfab Video wih timestamb (19:25)](https://youtu.be/pGWFX5TvOJc?t=1165)

Hi there,
I'm working a lot with measurement and planning PVpanels, it would really help a lot if i could rebuild a House quicker than i am used to atm.

But that's not the question that i would like to answered, is there a way to Projekt the Part, that aligns in the view with some selected Polygons/ Surfaces, to the 3D Model as a texture. (As shown in the Video above)

This you see is done with just 2 Pictures, a photogrammetry scan would need alot more pictures.

[image: Texture baking to marked surface - Roof]

There you can see, 1 Marked surface (Roof) with a Picture infront/aligned with the 3D Object. Rightclick and "ProjectPhoto" bakes the Seen Texture on the Object, he have to repeat all steps for all surfaces, and ohter Pictures from a different perspective. To get something like that:
[image: Example 1]

[image]

Comment: yeah thats not what i want to do, already using fspy.
ill get some Screenshots

Comment: Camera mapped projected textures may be what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NYNiayHvJI

Comment: i am feeling stupid, i was searching alot and didnt find that. 
I watched it and it seems like it could solve my prob. Gonna try it. 

Thx alot! Case closed